WPF IsMouseOver stays true when moving to parent form
I am having a very strange issue and am unable to find an answer anywhere.
I am using WindowChrome to make my own Window title bar to be able to remove the window icon and only have the close button. Here is the XAML
<Window x:Class="TestProject.testWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RadScene"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="" Height="420" Width="370" BorderBrush="#006cc1" BorderThickness="0.7" WindowStyle="None">
    <WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
        <WindowChrome CaptionHeight="30" />
    </WindowChrome.WindowChrome>

    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="TitleBarButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
                <Setter Property="WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome" Value="True" />
                <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <Grid x:Name="border" Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Focusable="False" RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                            </Grid>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                    <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="CloseButtonStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource TitleBarButtonStyle}"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Height="30" Background="white">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock Text="Caption" FontSize="16" Foreground="#006cc1" Margin="5 3 0 0" />
            </StackPanel>

            <!--Caption buttons-->
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" >
                <Button x:Name="buttonClose" Style="{StaticResource CloseButtonStyle}">
                    <Path Width="46" Height="32" Data="M 18,11 27,20 M 18,20 27,11" Stroke="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}" StrokeThickness="0.6" />
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>

    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Margin="10" Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock Text="Content" Margin="0,5,0,0" FontSize="15" Foreground="#646464">Time</TextBlock>            
    </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</Window>

And the cs code
        testWindow tw = new testWindow();
        tw.Owner = this;
        tw.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
        tw.ShowDialog();

Everything works great, EXCEPT the IsMouseOver event does not seem to turn false when moving from the button in the right direction to the parent form (see screenshot below). All other directions work fine. If I move the child window off the parent form, everything works fine. I can't figure this out so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update - Emoacht pointed out that the culprit is the ShowDialog() since it does not seem to happen with just Show().

I cannot reproduce your issue. There could be some other factor you have not shared.

@emoacht That's strange. The only thing I didn't include is that the WindowStyle is set to "None" and the button is within a Grid and StackPanel. Aside from that, the WIndow owner is set to the parent and that's about it. At least this tells me it's something with my setup/version as opposed to the code itself. Thanks

Unless you include the code of The only thing I didn't include is that the WindowStyle is set to "None" and the button is within a Grid and StackPanel, your code is not ready to be tested by others.

@emoacht I added the entire xaml and the portion of the cs code. Thank you for clarifying

All the StackPanels are redundant. I'd start by removing them. Any StackPanel with a single item is redundant.

I got it. It reproduced. The point is ShowDialog method. It won't happen if the window is shown by Show method. I have no idea on the workaround at this moment.

@emoacht Interesting. I didn't even think to check that. At least it gives me somewhere to start. Thank you for the advice and direction!
